# Filtering query with join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using ColdFusion 8 to develop my company's website and would like to return a list of records (just the `clientname` field) from a table (`dbo.clients`) that has no match in a different table (`dbo.fees`) for the purpose of prompting the end-user to add a fee schedule for those companies.  An example:

dbo.clients

```
CLIENT_ID CLIENT_NAME
1         Joe's Diner
2         Save-a-Lot
3         Family Meds
4         DiFazio's
```

dbo.fees

```
CID        CLIENT_NAME  FEE
1          Joe's Diner  25.000
2          Save-a-Lot   35.000
4          DiFazio's    30.000
```

What I desire is a resultset that, in the case of the above tables/data, would return only clientid/clientname 3/Family Meds because they do not have a fee listed/record in the table `dbo.fees`.  My DB is MSSQL 2005.  My query is:

```
SELECT clientid 
FROM clients 
INNER JOIN fees 
  ON clients.clientid <> fees.cid;
```

Which returns a Cartesian product of 50,000+ results. Using `LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN` still gives me a Cartesian product and `DISTINCT` simply returns every record from `dbo.clients` regardless of whether or not they have a `dbo.fees` entry or not.  What am I doing wrong?

p.s. Also of note: The admin before me apparently did not set up a PK/FK relationship between the clients/fees tables and so any query syntax that might be reliant on that may not work in this situation.  It would probably have to work based solely on the values of the relevant fields.

Comment: FYI, you're better off saying "SQL Server 2005" rather than "MSSQL 2005". "MSSQL" is not the name of the product, and can be mistaken for "MYSQL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause that will return only those records that do not appear in the `fees` table:

```
select c.CLIENT_ID, c.CLIENT_NAME
from clients c
left join fees f
    on c.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID
where f.CLIENT_ID is null
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great reference:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

This can also be written using a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from clients c
where not exists (select CLIENT_ID
                    from fees f
                    where c.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID)
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/293bc/1) with both queries

Comment: Thanks Bluefeet, I saw a similar Venn Diagram explanation but your link is much better, showing the actual tables as well.  And thank you for your help on the syntax.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest, you could just use a `NOT IN`;

```
SELECT clientid FROM clients WHERE clientid NOT IN
  (SELECT clientid FROM fees)
```

...or you can use a LEFT JOIN to do the same thing a bit more verbosely; f.clientid will be NULL if a fee does not exist for the client.

```
SELECT c.clientid
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN fees f
ON c.clientid = f.clientid
WHERE f.clientid IS NULL
```